# MS graph "Multiple Customer" Bookings - Unable to retrieve customer information

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

How to retrieve multiple customer bookings customer data from MS Graph?

MS Graph is the API to access MS Bookings. I am attempting to retrieve customer information, which works for bookings with single customers. However you can have multiple customers.

[API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingappointment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Here are the api calls for a single customer, to access bookings.

**1  Get User Token**

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

**2 Get List of Bookings for date period**

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/{{BookingBusinessId}}/appointments](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/%7B%7BBookingBusinessId%7D%7D/appointments)

**3  Get Booking with ID**

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/{{BookingBusinessId}}/appointments/{{BookingId}}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/%7B%7BBookingBusinessId%7D%7D/appointments/%7B%7BBookingId%7D%7D)

The response object for a single customer booking, will include the following for customer information in the json object. However the multiple, will provide null. Pls Note, I have blanked out most values and represented this with a leading and ending "_".

*Single customer booking*

```
        "id": "_bookid_",
        "selfServiceAppointmentId": "_selfserviceappId_",
        "additionalInformation": "",
        "isLocationOnline": true,
        "onlineMeetingUrl": "_teamsbookingid_",
        "customerId": "_CustomerId_",
        "customerName": "_customerName_",
        "customerEmailAddress": "_email_",
        "customerPhone": "_phone_",
        "customerNotes": "_notes_",
```

*Multiple customer booking*

```
        "id": "[bookid]",
        "selfServiceAppointmentId": "[selfserviceappId]",
        "additionalInformation": "",
        "isLocationOnline": false,
        "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
        "customerId": null,
        "customerName": null,
        "customerEmailAddress": null,
        "customerPhone": null,
        "customerNotes": null,
```

The Calendar view delta object will instead of listing the customer details, will add the following note.

"NOTE: This is a Multi customer booking. Log into Bookings to see customer information and notes for this event."

Has anyone been able to solve multi customer bookings with MS Graph to retrieve customer data?

Comment: Looks like the same issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10385

Comment: thanks, yes its the same issue. Also seems as though hope is lost.

Comment: Glad to hear that the above info shared by @ShivaKeshavVarma helped. Thanks for confirming it.